# How to make the client download a static file from a custom module on clicking a button?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

**Odoo 14 Community Edition**

I have a custom module with a custom model inside it.

I created a custom view. It is working correctly.

Now that I need to add a button that let the client download a static file from the server.

The file should be put in the module folder, which I am still not sure where to put it, because of modularization.

Assume the button is created with a method for it correctly, how do I implement this and where should I put the file in order for it to work?

*Note: It is just a normal PDF file. Think of it as a button to download a manual document.*

Comment: Are you sure the PDF will never change? Sounds more like a changeable binary field on `res.company` or a char field with an URI.

Comment: @CZoellner It can be changed in the future by me changing the file in the module, but the filename will stay the same -- just essentially update the file. The point is that the file is not supposed to be changable by users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return this object in the method of the button.

```
def download_static_file(self):
    return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_url', 'url': '/your_module_name/static/src/target_file.pdf', 'target': 'self'}
```

Also, put the file in the path above properly. I have tested **.pdf** and **.xlsx**. They both work.

Comment: every file should work on odoo-site. there's probably something in the used browser blocking some files.

Comment: @CZoellner You mean that there are going to be some files that get blocked by browser?

Comment: i hope so, like .pdf.exe but probably not :/

Comment: Okay. So for future readers, be wary that this method may likely have security issues.